# replace nav bar with back ground color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the twitter bootstrap to develop a responsive website....
When I reduce the browser window the navigation bar collapses....
But in the collapsed nav bar i need to show background color....
But it shows background image. How to replace it with `background-color: #14486b;`
I am not sure from where does this back ground image coming up

```
<div class="nav-collapse in collapse" style="height: auto;">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/docs/examples/product.html">Product</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/solution.html">Solutions</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/service.html">Services</a></li>
              <li class="iphonePartnerLink"><a href="/docs/examples/partner.html">Partners</a></li>
              <li class="iphoneContactLink"><a href="/docs/examples/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav" id="navSecond">
              <li class=""><a href="/docs/examples/partners.html">Partners</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
              <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
              <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: provide link please ...

Comment: .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner{
              /*background-image:url('http://www.defie.co/designerImages/bg_bar.png');*/
              background-color: red;
            }

Comment: Do you have a navbar-inner div surrounding the current div .

Comment: Can you post the whole navbar code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/KNPZB/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Try to analyze, where the image is coming from.
Good tools to do so are Firebug for Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/
or the development tools of Chrome (Press F12 in Chrome to open it). In both tools you can inspect single componentens of the DOM tree an see all attached CSS styles (and its source).

If the reason is a background-image you can overwrite the style in the following way:

```
#idOfComponent {
    background-image:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace the image by the background color using media queries :

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

         .navbar-inner{
                 background-image: url("http://www.defie.co/designerImages/bg_bar.png");/*remove this */
                 background-color:#14486b;
               }

           }

 /* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
  @media (max-width: 767px) {

           .navbar-inner{
                 background-image: url("http://www.defie.co/designerImages/bg_bar.png");
                 background-color:#14486b;
               }
        }

 /* Landscape phones and down */
  @media (max-width: 480px) {

             .navbar-inner{
                 background-image: url("http://www.defie.co/designerImages/bg_bar.png");
                 background-color:#14486b;
               }
        }
```

If you want to fix the navbar on top:

```
.navbar {
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;/*remove this line if you want to fix it */
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
  }
```

Edit After comment : YOu have set your background-image to none in media queries and the color is commented out like this:

```
@media (max-width:980px){
         .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner{
          background-image: none;
          /*background-color: red;*/
        }
       }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
     .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
  background-image: none;
    /*background-color: red;*/
     }
    }

    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner{
          background-image: none;
          /*background-color: red;*/
        }
      }
```

Please replace the styles with the one I mentioned above.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/KNPZB/1/embedded/result/ yeah it works but the main bar which should have a background image gets disappear....how to resolve it....

Comment: As far as I can see you wanted to put a background color inplace of image . What exactly do you want?

Comment: when u reduce the browser i want the nav bar with the back ground image

Comment: Rajkumar the above queries will help you get your nav  with background image on iphone tablet

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KNPZB/3/embedded/result/ i updated in the fiddle its not working

Comment: Rajkumar I have found the issue , you have not used the above queries as I stated . By the way do you need background color while you resize because in the above comment you mentioned background image.